# SQL query to find people where age is below a certain value

Tags: sql, db2

I am attempting to find all persons who are below the age of 40, I have attempted a query after looking through documentation:

```
SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName
FROM Person AS p
WHERE 40 <= DATEDIFF(CURRENT DATE, p.DateOfBirth, 'YEAR');
```

However I am returned an error stating:

```
No authorized routine named "DATEDIFF" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was 
found
```

Yet I have seen DATEDIFF used in DB2 SQL before.

Comment: Try a different logic instead compare the birthdate with the current date minus 40 years. Single calculation and much more efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `year` function:

`SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName
FROM Person AS p
WHERE year(current date - dateofbirth)  < 40`

Comment: year(current date - dateofbirth) < 40

Comment: Warning, this may ignore any indices, because you're calling a function on a column in the search criteria.

Answer (score 2):

`p.DateOfBirth >= current date - 40 years`

Answer (score 0):

less than 40 years...

```
SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName
FROM Person AS p
WHERE  dateofbirth + 40 years >= current date
```

Comment: And when you switch the calculation it's even better :-)  `WHERE  dateofbirth >= current_date - 40 years`